# Weird webpage loading behaviour

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting

I have a website that I'm hosting on a public IP using IIS 7.0. (using c# asp.net 3.5)

I find that if I navigate to the webpage for the first time in a day. It loads endlessly and nothing shows up. Then when I re-press enter in the address bar, it loads right away and everything works fine.

From then on, when I got to the address again it loads quickly.

I don't think this is a compilation issue as all my code is pre-compiled.

Any ideas what might be causing this behavior?

Thanks!
Andrew

Comment: Are you using a Global.asax file? It sounds like perhaps your authentication code has issues.

Comment: I'm not. I can look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which turned out to be caused by the IIS app pool recycling.

In my case, the website had outgrown its hosting package and as soon as it hit the arbitrary memory limit, the app pool was recycled and the application restarted, recompiling on the first page view.

You can check for this by adding a Global.asax and handling the `Application_Start` event. You could write logs to a database or send an email notification with whatever debug details you want.

I also handle `Application_Error` which offered up some useful info.

If you notice `Application_Start` happening several times a day, you may have a memory leak or similar issue.